# Parsing xml in python gives null values

Tags: python-2.7, xml-parsing

I'm programming in python and I'm trying to read the status of my Yamaha network stereo.  I get the following xml response

```
<YAMAHA_AV rsp="GET" RC="0">
    <System>
        <Power_Control>
            <Power>On</Power>
        </Power_Control>
    </System>
</YAMAHA_AV>
```

All good so far.  Now, I'm trying to search for Power to get the latest status.  It is there in XML but I can't locate the Power Status value when I use a XML parser such as Elementtree.

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

url = "http://192.168.128.199/YamahaRemoteControl/ctrl"

payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<YAMAHA_AV cmd=\"GET\">\r\n<System>\r\n    <Power_Control>\r\n        <Power>GetParam</Power>\r\n    </Power_Control>\r\n</System>\r\n</YAMAHA_AV>"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "text/xml",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "9ad57fc1-4c78-a921-5967-bef4d2167214"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
rawdata=ET.fromstring(response.content)
result= rawdata.find('Power').text
print (result)
result = rawdata.items()
print(result)
```

I get a null value.  So I step through python interactive and I can see findall and findtext attribute when I use dir() function on the root but not on the subelements.

```
>>> root=ET.parse('yamahaPowerStatus.xml').getroot()
>>> print root
<Element 'YAMAHA_AV' at 0x6386bb0>
>>> PC=root.getchildren()[0].getchildren()
>>> print PC
[<Element 'Power_Control' at 0x6386cf0>]
>>> check= PC.findtext('Power')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    check= PC.findtext('Power')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findtext'
```

> > > dir(PC)
> > >           ['**add**', '**class**', '**contains**', '**delattr**', '**delitem**', '**delslice**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**', '**getslice**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**iadd**', '**imul**', '**init**', '**iter**', '**le**', '**len**', '**lt**', '**mul**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**reversed**', '**rmul**', '**setattr**', '**setitem**', '**setslice**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
> > >
> > > dir (root)
> > >       ['**class**', '**delattr**', '**delitem**', '**dict**', '**doc**', '**format**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**len**', '**module**', '**new**', '**nonzero**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**setitem**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_children', 'append', 'attrib', 'clear', 'copy', 'extend', 'find', 'findall', 'findtext', 'get', 'getchildren', 'getiterator', 'insert', 'items', 'iter', 'iterfind', 'itertext', 'keys', 'makeelement', 'remove', 'set', 'tag', 'tail', 'text']

So what am I'm doing wrong?  The XML response appears to be properly formatted.  I tried using other XML parsers but the same result.  I also tried converting it to JSON first but the same result.  I reviewed youtube videos and I tried to locate something similar here with no luck. I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand why this works so I'm open to comments.  For some reason, I have to use a 'for loop' even though I know there is only one entry.

```
tree=ET.fromstring(response.content)
for power_name in tree.findall('.//Power_Control/Power'):
    result= power_name.text
print result
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findtext'`. The error clearly states that it is a list element. In this case the list only contains one element. Thus you need to use a loop. Hope that clarifies it.